# What newspapers/magazines would people have used in Solloghodmore Ireland around 1850?

Tags: 19th-century, ireland, newspaper

What newspapers, magazines, etc would people have used in Solloghodmore/Solloghod-more around 1800-1899?

I'm looking for:

- death notices
- news stories
- advertising
- etc

Basically looking for information around the areas of Drumwood, Chadville, Clonganhue and Moanmore.

Comment: YOu'll have seen https://www.johngrenham.com/c_parish/c_parish_main.php?civilparishid=2291&civilparish=Solloghodmore&county=South%20Tipperary which gives a general list of newspapers for Tipperary...

Comment: Oh nice it gives a lot of sources that I can look up for information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most countries have what was called a "Union List of Newspapers", published by their National Library.  These are now being migrated to online catalogues and databases.  As SOLLOGHODMORE is in Tipperary a search of this database on The National Library of Ireland website should help: https://www.nli.ie/en/catalogues-and-databases-printed-newspapers.aspx. For online access you need to check the Irish Newspaper Archive (https://www.irishnewsarchive.com/) and/or the British Newspaper Archive.  If there is nothing to assist your search I would look at contacting the local county library service who may be able to provide more specific information.